# Max value of a function MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the max value of this function in MATLAB, `ln(x^sqrt(2))-x^3+4`. I know how to find the min using `fminbnd` but I do not know how to go about finding the max value of the function.

Comment: Apply `fminbnd` to the negative of the function?

Comment: Multiply it by `-1`.

Comment: okay i will try that thanks!

Comment: I am reviving an error saying: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in fminsearch (line 189)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Comment: my code look like:                                                                                        x =@(x) (log(x).^(sqrt(2)) - x.^3 + 4).* -1;  
max = fminsearch(x,[-inf inf]);  
print(max);

Comment: (1) `fminsearch` expects a scalar output; `[-inf,inf]` generates a `1x2` output, so an error is thrown. (2) For 1D searches, `fminsearch` should only be given a scalar input for the initial guess. (3) `fminsearch` is boundless. (4) There is a huge difference between `log(x).^(sqrt(2)) ` and `log(x.^(sqrt(2)))` which one is your function?

Comment: my function is log(x.^(sqrt(2)))

Comment: Then everything should be fine with either `fminsearch` (with a good guess value) or `fminbnd` (with a finite, positive guess region).

Comment: yeah i just had to change the range it works now. thanks alot!

Comment: max is `3.1741` at `x=0.7783`